# Django migration error in change model ('Duplicate key name')

Tags: django, django-models, django-migrations

I have a field of a model in Django that I have changed and added unique = True, because I want everything now entered in that field to be different. The problem is, if I have in the database equal values ​​in that field that are saved from the past, I miss an error in the migration. My question is whether there is any way to make a condition for that in the migration or the model, and if there are values ​​of the same field in the database before, that ignore or save the first and put the others to NULL.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Unfortunately a `NULL` value will also raise duplicate constraints, if the column is set to be unique.

Comment: None that I know of, I will recommend writing a script to manually change the values of duplicate fields and add 4-5 random char to end of it. Or just add a 4-5 random char to end of the field in all rows, considering its a char, text etc. field. Not an integer field.